# Bethe approximation for factor graphs

Tags: graphical-model, variational-bayes, approximate-inference, belief-propagation

I am confused at computing Bethe approximation for factor graphs in [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d25f/1810fce8d830f2337fe704fee13501a83465.pdf). It generalizes Bethe approxmiation in a pairwise case. However, I am wondering why (75) goes to (78) with (76):
[image]

We can verify that

$$\hat b_i(x_i)\propto \exp\left[(d_i-1)^{-1}\sum_{a\in N_i}\lambda_{ai}(x_i)\right]$$

$$\begin{align}\hat b_i(x_i)&\propto \exp\left[(d_i-1)^{-1}\sum_{a\in N_i}\lambda_{ai}(x_i)\right]\\
&=\prod_{a\in N(i)}\exp\left[(d_i-1)^{-1}\lambda_{ai}(x_i)\right]
\end{align}$$

Since (76) involves $m_{\text{fact}\rightarrow\text{singleton}}$, it's tempting to use the second equation in (76), and thus we have

$$\begin{align}\hat b_i(x_i)&\propto \prod_{a\in N_i}\exp\left[\log \prod_{c\in N_i\backslash a}m_{c\rightarrow i}(x_i)^{\frac1{d_i-1}}\right]
\end{align}
$$

Then everything is messed up. I do not see why after canceling $\exp$ and $\log$ we obtain $m_{a\rightarrow i}(x_i)$.

There are several references where $m_{a\rightarrow i}$ all comes out mysteriously. I am looking for help in this derivation.

Other refs:

- p. 28 [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~epxing/Class/10708-16/slide/lecture12-BP.pdf):

[image]

- p. 24 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.2168.pdf):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

after some efforts with a friend of mine and this book [chapter](https://web.stanford.edu/~montanar/RESEARCH/BOOK/partD.pdf),

I think I kinda worked it out.

[image]

[image]

[image]